# How do I add coalesce into this query?

Tags: sql, coalesce

I have a query with several sub-queries added on using Cross Joins. This tracks purchases, sales, proceeds and profit.

It works perfectly if there's purchases and sales, but when there's only purchases and no sales, it falls apart. The query returns nothing, instead of just showing for example 1,000,000 tokens bought and 0 tokens sold.

```
CROSS JOIN

(select  
    Sum(CASE 
    WHEN ttsfm.contract_address = '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3' then ttsfm.value/1000
    ELSE ttsfm.value
    END)/1e9 AS Safemoon_sold, 
sum(distinct(ttbnb.value)/1e18) as BNB_proceeds, sum(distinct(pusd.price*ttbnb.value)/1e18) as USD_Proceeds, count(distinct(tx.hash)) as Sales

from bsc.transactions tx
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttsfm on tx.hash = ttsfm.evt_tx_hash
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttbnb on tx.hash = ttbnb.evt_tx_hash
left join prices.usd pusd on date_trunc('minute', tx.block_time) = pusd.minute
where ttsfm.contract_address in ('\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5', '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3') --V2 & V1 contract addresses
and ttbnb.contract_address = '\xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'
and tx.from in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and ttsfm.from in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and pusd.symbol = 'WBNB'
and left(tx.data::varchar, 10) in ('\x18cbafe5', '\x4a25d94a', '\x791ac947', '\x8803dbee', '\x5c11d795', '\x38ed1739')
group by tx."from") as Sells

CROSS JOIN
```

Where do I add coalesce in here? There are four columns I'm returning - Safemoon_Sold, BNB_proceeds, USD_Proceeds and Sales.

I think the issue is that I'm finding the sum of all sales.

The below is my entire query. It finds all purchases of a scam cryptocurrency, how much BNB was spent to get it, how much that BNB is worth, how many sales there are. How much Safemoon was sold, how much BNB was returned, how much that returned BNB is worth, how many sales there have been, how many transfers in and transfers out there have been, what the current balance is, and then finally the profit/loss figure & the percentage gained/lost.

```
with Calcs as (

SELECT * FROM
  (select tx."from", Sum(CASE 
    WHEN tt.contract_address = '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3' then tt.value/1000
    ELSE tt.value
    END)/1e9 AS Safemoon_Bought, sum(ttbnb.value/1e18) as BNB_Spent, sum(pusd.price*ttbnb.value/1e18) as TxCosts, count(tx.from) as purchases
    
from bsc.transactions tx
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" tt on tx.hash = tt.evt_tx_hash
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttbnb on tx.hash = ttbnb.evt_tx_hash
left join prices.usd pusd on date_trunc('minute', tx.block_time) = pusd.minute
where tt.contract_address in ('\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5', '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3') --V2 & V1 contract addresses
and ttbnb.contract_address = '\xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'
and tx.from in('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and tt.to in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and pusd.symbol = 'WBNB'
and left(tx.data::varchar, 10) not in ('\x454b0608', '\xbaa2abde')
group by tx."from")   AS Buys

CROSS JOIN

coalesce(select  
    Sum(CASE 
    WHEN ttsfm.contract_address = '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3' then ttsfm.value/1000
    ELSE ttsfm.value
    END)/1e9 AS Safemoon_sold, 
sum(distinct(ttbnb.value)/1e18) as BNB_proceeds, sum(distinct(pusd.price*ttbnb.value)/1e18) as USD_Proceeds, count(distinct(tx.hash)) as Sales

from bsc.transactions tx
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttsfm on tx.hash = ttsfm.evt_tx_hash
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttbnb on tx.hash = ttbnb.evt_tx_hash
left join prices.usd pusd on date_trunc('minute', tx.block_time) = pusd.minute
where ttsfm.contract_address in ('\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5', '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3') --V2 & V1 contract addresses
and ttbnb.contract_address = '\xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'
and tx.from in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and ttsfm.from in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and pusd.symbol = 'WBNB'
and left(tx.data::varchar, 10) in ('\x18cbafe5', '\x4a25d94a', '\x791ac947', '\x8803dbee', '\x5c11d795', '\x38ed1739')
group by tx."from"),0) as Sells

CROSS JOIN

(select Sum(CASE 
            WHEN ttin.contract_address = '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3' then ttin.value/1000
            ELSE ttin.value
        END)/1e9 AS TransfersIn,
        Sum(CASE 
            WHEN ttout.contract_address = '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3' then ttout.value/1000
            ELSE ttout.value
        END)/1e9 AS TransfersOut
from bsc.transactions tx
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttin on tx.hash = ttin.evt_tx_hash
left join bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer" ttout on tx.hash = ttout.evt_tx_hash
where ttin.contract_address in ('\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5', '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3') --V2 & V1 contract addresses
and  ttout.contract_address in ('\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5', '\x8076C74C5e3F5852037F31Ff0093Eeb8c8ADd8D3') --V2 & V1 contract addresses
and  ttin.to in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and ttout.to in ('{{Wallet}}') --Owner Wallet Address
and ttin.from <> '\x678ee23173dce625a90ed651e91ca5138149f590' --V2Deployer
and ttout.to <> '\x678ee23173dce625a90ed651e91ca5138149f590' --V2Deployer
and left(tx.data::varchar, 10) = '\xa9059cbb'
) as Transfers

CROSS JOIN

(with
        transfers AS (
        
            --Inflow
            SELECT  "value" as amount
            FROM bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer"
            WHERE   "to" in ('{{Wallet}}') -- Owner Wallet
            AND     "contract_address" = '\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5' -- V2
                    
            UNION ALL
            --Outflow
            SELECT  -"value"/0.96 as amount
            FROM bep20."BEP20_evt_Transfer"
            WHERE   "from" in ('{{Wallet}}')  -- Owner Wallet 
            AND     "contract_address" = '\x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5'  -- V2
            )
    SELECT 
        CASE when sum(t.amount/1e9) <0 then 0
        else sum(t.amount/1e9)
        end as balance
    FROM transfers t) as Balances

)
select *, (usd_proceeds+(Balance*0.00038)) - txcosts as Profit, (usd_proceeds+(balance*0.00038)-txcosts)/txcosts as Percentage from Calcs
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I think the issue here is that there are 4 columns I'm taking from the "Sales" cross join. When I delete 3 of them and run Coalesce, it returns a 0 as expected. So how do I coalesce a subquery with multiple columns?

Comment: I think you would need to show the full query for anyone to help you - but I'm guessing that using cross joins may not be the solution so you may be better off explaining what you are trying to achieve (with sample data and expected results) rather that asking for help with your solution

Comment: Hi Nick, I've updated the main post with the full SQL.

If someone has bought 10 times and sold 2 times, it should their purchases, their sales, their cost and their proceeds, in addition to a profit/loss. When people buy AND sell this works.

When people only buy and haven't sold yet, instead of returning 0, it returns null, which then nullifies the whole query.

Comment: Did you try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: Hi @UserControl - thanks for the suggestion, that did not work, the query would not run.

It should surely be possible to return a 0 if there is nothing to sum with the coalesce command?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to look into this. One remark though: When you outer join a table, e.g. `pusd`, and then have a where condition like `and pusd.symbol = 'WBNB'`, you dismiss all outer joined rows, because their values are all null. You are turning your outer joins into inner joins. Criteria on outer joined tables belong into their `ON` clause.